# dcast and aggregate to length in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
   ID   credit_active    credit_currency      credit_type
   1    Active           Dollars              Home
   1    Closed           Dollars              Home
   1    Active           Euro                 Home
   2    Active           Dollars              Home
   2    Closed           Dollars              Home
   2    Active           Euro                 Home
```

I want data in following format

```
   ID     Active    Closed     Dollars     Euro     Home
   1      2         1          2           1        3
   2      2         1          2           1        3
```

I am using dcast function to do above

```
  dcast_bureau <- dcast(setDT(bureau),ID~ credit_active + credit_currency + credit_type,
                  value.var = c("credit_active ","credit_currency ","credit_type")
                  ,fun.aggregate = length)
```

But it does not give me my desired format. 
How can I do it in r?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to `melt` and `dcast`.  If there are duplicate elements, by default, the `fun.aggregate` is `length`

```
dcast(melt(setDT(bureau), id.var = 'ID'), ID ~ value)
#    ID Active Closed Dollars Euro Home
#1:  1      2      1       2    1    3
#2:  2      2      1       2    1    3
```

In `reshape2`, there is a convenient wrapper `recast` (`melt` + `dcast`) which would make it more compact

```
library(reshape2)
recast(bureau, id.var = 'ID', ID ~ value)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Why did not it worked,the way I was doing it?

Comment: @Neil In the formula, you are using all the combinations along with 3 value.var columns.  so, individually, these values will be of length 1 instead of taking the whole into consideration